# Is there a way of telling if a device can send text messages or just iMessage?

Tags: sms, ios5

I have an app that is configured to send in-app sms messages to a defined number. In viewDidLoad I check to see if the device can send text messages using [MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText] and then hide the control if it's not supported by the device.

This has worked fine up until now, but now I'm updating it for iOS 5 and have found devices that don't support SMS, but do support iMessage receive a YES message from [MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText].

As the receiving number is not an iOS 5 device, any messages sent on the iMessage service fail. Just to make things worse, the delegate method messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult: reports MessageComposeResultSent, so I can't even display a message after the event. The only time a user gets to see that the message wasn't delivered is if they look in the messaging app, the messages are then marked as 'Not Delivered'.

So, is there a way of querying the device to find out if it can send 'real' sms messages or if it's just got iMessage support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to determine, if your current device can make calls by:
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"tel://"]]

And if this returns YES, you know your device has GSM/CDMA module, that means you can send SMS. If you get NO, you can send iMessage only.

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more granular than this and that I'd missed something in the docs, but this seems to make sense. It would seem that iOS 5 has rendered +canSendText rather obsolete, as all iOS 5 devices are going to return YES. I think this is probably as close as I'm going to get. Maybe there will be +canSendSMS and +canSendiMessage in a future release.

Comment: don't forget about a notification they've added for tracking the canSendSMS flag changes... if you're on iPod touch and lost your wifi connection, you'll receive this notification, because you won't be able to send iMessages without active connection

Comment: @MattGarrod + canSendText is still useful cuz if there's no cellular network and iMessage not configured than it's gonna return NO.

Comment: @Denis, this' genius.. I just posted a similar question wish I'd have found it earlier. Though there's a small problem that, for the particular scenario I am in, I need to know the exact mechanism by which text will be sent. Anyways, something is better than nothing :).. Thanks